# BindingProxy for XAML in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have previously used the following code I found somewhere to implement a BindingProxy in WPF.

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have tried to create a similar class for my Xamarin application which looks like this.

```
public class BindingProxy : BindableObject
{

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), null);


    public object Data
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This is the closest I could come up with to the Freezable class in Xamarin, unfortunately however when I declare my xaml as so

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <binding:BindingProxy x:Key="BindingProxy" Data="{Binding BindingContext}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

the `Data` property is never set to the BindingContext (or any other value) and returns the default value (null).

Can anyone provide any insight to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: According to your description, I am not sure if you want to use BindableProperty, If yes, you can take a look the following article firstly:https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/, it is used to create custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/51280/xaml-binding-within-a-resource-dictionary-contentpage-resources-does-not-work) resources are not provided with the BindingContext and therefore do not support databinding.
Depending on your use case there might be another option to get the specific BindingContext, so you maybe want to explain that a little.